# Are my answers for these propositional calculus questions right?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, solution-verification

Formalize the following English sentences as propositional logic formulas:

$i)\quad$ "When the front and back doors are closed then the light is off."

$ii)\quad$ "Either the lift doors are open or the lift is moving and the lift doors are closed."

I)

- P- "front and back doors are closed"
- Q- "the light is off"

  Q ⇒ P

II) P - "life doors are open" q - "the lift is moving"

I have two answers for this since I wasn't too sure

**¬**P ⇒ q ∨ (P)

or

P ∨ (q∧**¬**P)

---

Formalize the following English sentences as propositional logic formulas:

$i)\quad$ "Either the brake is off and the car is moving or the brake is on and the car is parked."

$ii)\quad$ "If the valve is open then the light is on and the door is closed."

i)

- P  - the break is off
- q- the car is moving
- r - the car is parked
  P ∧ q ∨(q**¬**∧r)

ii)

- p - the valve is open
- q - light is on
- r - the door is closed
   q ∧ r ⇒ P

---

Formalize the following English sentences as propositional logic formulas:

$i)\quad$ "The alarm is on whenever the house is empty and the door is locked."

$ii)\quad$ "Either the light is on, or if the door is locked then the light is off and the door is locked."

- P - alarm is on
- q - the house is empty
- r - the door is locked

i)P ⇒ q∧r

ii)

- P - the light is on ,
- q - the door is closed
- r - the alarm is on

P ∨ q ⇒ **¬**p ∧ r

Comment: That's some crazy electronics. I'd like to see the [logic gates](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) for these $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to use parentheses to group an entire propositional clause.

For the first, I'd suggest you designate

$p: $ front door is closed. $\quad q :$ back door is closed. $\quad r:$ the door is locked.

$$(p \land q) \rightarrow r\tag{I}$$

For the first, II: the second translation is correct: $p \lor (q \land \lnot p)\tag{II}$

---

For the second question,

- i: $(p\land q) \lor (\lnot p \land r)$.
- ii: $p \rightarrow (q \land r)$.

---

For the last question, "The alarm is on whenever the house is empty and the door is locked." This can be stated as follows: "If the house is empty and the door is locked, then the alarm is on." Using your key, this gives us:

$$(q \land r)\rightarrow p\tag{i}$$

For part (ii), you need parentheses: $$p \lor (q\rightarrow(\lnot p \land r))\tag{ii}$$

Comment: I know this is probably idiotic, but I don't really understand parentheses; I have no idea where they should be allocated. Thanks for taking your time btw.